# how to print 09 if the int variable is 9 in C?

Tags: c

any existing function to do that in c?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

sprintf with formatting codes like %02d will give you two decimal places.

here's an example of the command
sprintf( string, "file.%d", file_number );

Here it puts the string "file.2" into the variable named string, assuming that 2 was in the variable named file_number.

you can use multiple like so:
sprintf(str, "%02d/%02d/%4d",day,month,year);

Look up the specs on sprintf for other kinds of formatting like floating point significant digits.

Comment: Silly question - why `%02d` rather than `%2d`? Is the leading zero needed? If so, why is `%4d` OK?

Comment: @Steve314: `%2d` will pad with spaces, `%02d` with 0s.  `%4d` is presumably OK because the code is only specified to work with years after 999 ;)

Comment: @caf - OK, I guess we can tolerate that particular millenium bug

Answer (score 3):

Along with `"%02d"` you can use `"%2.2d"` if you prefer. The latter style is handy when/if the actual width is in a variable so you do something like this:

```
int width = 2;
int value = 9;

printf("%*.*d", width, width, value);
```

Comment: The first `2` in `%2.2d` is superfluous - `%.2d` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%02d", 9);
```